# WinForm No Longer TopMost?

Tags: c#, winforms, topmost

I have a program that has a form that is set to TopMost = true, but for some reason, when it was running, the form stopped being the TopMost form.  In my code, there is nothing that modifies this property of the form, so I have no idea what could have caused this.

Are there any known bugs with the TopMost property in Winforms that could be causing this?  Anything else?

Comment: The competition must have used UberTopMost.

Comment: I think it will only be topmost over other forms in your program whose **TopMost** property is false

Comment: @Henk, Yeah, is that in the next .Net version? ;)

Comment: @afaolek, Actually, it was behaving like a TopMost = false form.  There were other forms in the application that were open, and it still was not TopMost for those either.  Very strange!

Comment: @ Maybe it's a bug, then

Comment: @afaolek, the other forms in the program have TopMost set to false also.

Comment: What makes you say TopMost stopped working?  Were the other forms from your same app?  From other apps?

Comment: Hope you are you using Show() or ShowDialog() methods. Can you show how you use them? Or have a close look probably there may be some simple big in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your topmost window cannot be the owner of other windows for topmost to function as expected.
Check that `_topmost_form.OwnedForms` is empty.
If it is not try de-owning them with `_topmost_form.RemoveOwnedForm(_any_owned_forms)`.